How to combine Sequel.or with Sequel.like? (mssql or sqlite)
I use ruby and sequel in my programm.
I want to execute a deletion in my DB like
DELETE FROM db.tbl WHERE col1 = 'a' and (col2 LIKE '%xxx%' OR col2 LIKE '%yyy%')

But I fail to build the statement with sequel.
I tried to use Sequel.or together with Sequel.like:
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(
    Sequel.or([Sequel.like(:col2, '%xxx%'),Sequel.like(:col2, '%yyy%')])
    ).delete

This returns me a in ``or': must pass a conditions specifier to Sequel.or (Sequel::Error)
Using a regular expression is not possible with sequel and mssql.
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(Sequel.like(:col2, /xxx|yyy')).delete

What works is to do it with two statements:
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(Sequel.like(:col2, '%xxx%')).delete
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(Sequel.like(:col2, '%yyy%')).delete

But I would prefer to use or, I may get additional values.
A full MWE:
require 'sequel'
Sequel.extension :pretty_table  #Sequel::PrettyTable.print()/Sequel::PrettyTable.string()

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:tbl){
  primary_key :id
  field :col1, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
  field :col2, :type => :nvarchar, :size => 10
} #unless DB.table_exists?(:file)

DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'a', :col2 => 'axxx1')
DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'a', :col2 => 'a2')
DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'a', :col2 => 'ayyy3')

DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'b', :col2 => 'bxxx1')
DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'b', :col2 => 'b2')
DB[:tbl].insert(:col1 => 'b', :col2 => 'byyy3')

#Two statements without Sequel.or work
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(Sequel.like(:col2, '%xxx%')).delete
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(Sequel.like(:col2, '%yyy%')).delete

#Does not work
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: 'a').filter(
    Sequel.or([Sequel.like(:col2, '%xxx%'),Sequel.like(:col2, '%yyy%')])
    ).delete

sel = DB[:tbl]
Sequel::PrettyTable.print(sel, sel.columns)


You can use the bitwise OR operator to join the two LIKE conditions:
DB[:tbl].filter(col1: "a").filter(
  Sequel.like(:col2, "%xxx%") | Sequel.like(:col2, "%yyy%")
).delete

Output:
+--+----+-----+
|id|col1|col2 |
+--+----+-----+
| 2|a   |a2   |
| 4|b   |bxxx1|
| 5|b   |b2   |
| 6|b   |byyy3|
+--+----+-----+

This is the SQL query Sequel executes (from the logs):
DELETE FROM `tbl` WHERE ((`col1` = 'a') AND ((`col2` LIKE '%xxx%' ESCAPE '\') OR (`col2` LIKE '%yyy%' ESCAPE '\')))


It appears that since the column is the same you can just pass both patterns, e.g. Sequel.like(:col2, '%xxx%','%yyy%'). Docs
